# Looking for a standalone program to convert coordinate systems in a Shape file

Tags: gis

Does anyone know of a standalone program that will convert the coordinates in a Shape file to another coordinate system?  By this I mean a program outside of a full GIS package.  I have customers who need to convert shape files from one coordinate system to another so the file can be displayed in one of my company's programs.  I know that there are several shareware GIS programs that can do this.  But I am trying to avoid having to help my customers install and learn how to use a whole GIS package just to do coordinate conversions.  My ideal program would be one where the user points to the Shape file, picks the target coordinate system, then the program writes a new Shape file, using the target coordinate system.  Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Have you solve your problem ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. No I have not found what I was looking for.

Comment: you didn't say which software are you going to use it with that stand alone program ?

Comment: My company has a data analysis program that has a map display.  But our mapping tool only works with latitude/longitude locations.  So if a client has data with locations in another coordinate system (like UTM) our program won't plot the data on the map.

Comment: Ok, do what kind of data analysis do you have ? Are you able to export it to Microsoft Excel from the data analysis program ? Perhaps can you tell me the name of that software so I can look at ?

Comment: The product is PetroVisual.  It is a data analysis program directed towards petroleum engineers.  You can find information about at;  https://blrdigital.com/  We do have several incarnations from the base code for more general applications besides petroleum.  All of them can export you data to Excel.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to watch the  video.  In my mind, is there a option for you to export it to shapefile ?  Does your company have a GIS software ?  On that website you send me I don't see support to search for help .

Comment: We just redid our website and will talk to the person who did it about adding links to our online tutorials.  They show you the types of analyses that can be done.  Here is a link that lets you get to them.. https://vimeo.com/search?q=petrovisual   What sort of data are you working with?  The tutorials are for the incarnation for petroleum engineers, but our other incarnations have the same analysis tools.  I can set you up with a demo license.  I just need to know what your data input would be so to get you the correct version.

Comment: We don't have shapefile exports.  But we are working on adding more exports.  What map features would you want to plot on the map, then export?

Comment: Well, you could discuss about buying one a commerical GIS software, or download a open source free  GIS software if you like...  QGIS, ArcGIS , Global Mapper ...  ArcGIS is the product from ESRI and is very popular all over the world... They do have ArcGIS Pro which is like a cloud.   Google : GIS software ..

Comment: It might be good for you to go here https://gis.stackexchange.com/  post one there and see if someone else might have the similar situation to yours and give you some feedback . Otherwise those software I mention would export an excel file in those software as long as if they have the longitude and latitude to be able to view it.

Comment: I think Feature Manipulation Engine or FME might be what you are looking for: https://www.safe.com/fme/ ??